# sliding through divs using next and previous buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to slide through 2 different divs on my page with 2 buttons - next and previous.

it is basically like a setup wizard that you see while installing a software.

so here is the mark up:

```
<div id="container">

        <div id="box1" class="box">
            <button id="nxt">Next</button>
            <button id="prv">Previous</button>
        </div>
        <div id="box2" class="box">
            <button id="nxt">Next</button>
            <button id="prv">Previous</button>
        </div>

    </div>
```

and here is the JQuery for both buttons:

```
$('#nxt').click(function() {

                    $(this).parent(".box").animate({left: '-150%'}, 500 );
                    $(this).parent(".box").next(".box").animate({left: '50%'},500);
        });
 $('#prv').click(function() {

            $(this).parent(".box").animate({left: '150%'}, 500 );
            $(this).parent(".box").prev(".box").animate({left: '50%'},500);
            });
```

I am able to do perform the "next" operation but not the "previous" one, there is a mistake with jquery, please help me with that.

you can also have a glance at [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sameermanek/8zerws5g/)

Thank You

Comment: The previous command is working for me. If I press `previous` on the first page.

Comment: use class insted of id for buttons

Comment: Thanks guys, It works! :)

Comment: check this id with same name will not trigger the events change id to class https://jsfiddle.net/sameermanek/8zerws5g/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must not use same ids for multiple elements. Use class attribute instead, see below markup and jquery;

HTML: Change id to class for previous and next buttons

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="box1" class="box">
       <button class="nxt">Next</button>
       <button class="prv">Previous</button>
    </div>
    <div id="box2" class="box">
       <button class="nxt">Next</button>
       <button class="prv">Previous</button>
    </div>

</div>
```

jQuery: make changes in jquery selector for class attribute and keep rest of the code as it is.

```
$('.nxt').click(function() {
    $(this).parent(".box").animate({left: '-150%'}, 500 );
    $(this).parent(".box").next(".box").animate({left: '50%'},500);
});

$('.prv').click(function() {    
    $(this).parent(".box").animate({left: '150%'}, 500 );
    $(this).parent(".box").prev(".box").animate({left: '50%'},500);
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/8zerws5g/1/)**

Comment: happy to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

you have just missed `.animate({left: '-50%'}` in `$('#prv').click(function(){}`

**[JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/8zerws5g/3)**

Comment: still doesn't work, but nevermind, I got the perfect solution!

Answer (score 0):

You use same id for buttons in first div and in second div. It is not right and that's the source of problem. Check out [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cb7uysbv/1/) to see right version.

```js
$('#nxt').click(function() {
            $(this).parent(".box").animate({left: '-150%'}, 500 );
            $(this).parent(".box").next(".box").animate({left: '50%'},500);
});
$('#prv1').click(function() {
    $(this).parent(".box").animate({left: '150%'}, 500 );
    $(this).parent(".box").prev(".box").animate({left: '50%'},500);
});
```

```css
#container {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.box {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: white;
    height: 500px;
    line-height: 300px;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid black;
    left: 50%;
    top: 100px;
    margin-left: -25%;
}

#box2 {
    left: 150%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">

            <div id="box1" class="box">
                <button id="nxt">Next</button>
                <button id="prv">Previous</button>
            </div>
            <div id="box2" class="box">
                <button id="nxt1">Next</button>
                <button id="prv1">Previous</button>
            </div>

        </div>
```